# MySQL Database Structure

Tags: mysql, database

I will have a table with a few million entries and I have been wondering if it was smarter to create more than just this one table, even though they would all have the same structure? Would it save resources and would it be more efficient in the end?

This is my particular concern, because I plan creating a small search engine which indexes about 3.000.000 sites and each sites will have approximately 30 words that are being indexed. This is my structure right now

```
site
--id
--url

word
--id
--word

appearances
--site_id
--word_id
--score
```

Should I keep this structure? Or should I create tables for A words, B words, C words etc? Same with the appearances table

Comment: A few million entries! That's a starter database, the server will handle it sleep-walking.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I figured so, but it will be about 100.000.000 entries in just one table. The others aren't as much though. Does it take more CPU power to enter data into a "100.000.000 table" than it would take to enter into a million table? Well, is it significant?

Comment: If you are able to adequately index the transactions occurring on the table, there shouldn't be a problem. Rather than creating multiple tables, it is better to partition a single table using the tools available in your RDBMS. This retains the logical ease of addressing a single table with your queries, while still obtaining the benefits of multiple cylinders/heads for I/O. Transaction volume is more likely to be a constraint than row count.

Comment: Design your database, normalize it, and then test for performance. Leverage the tools available in your RDBMS as needed. If there is still a performance issue, worry about "tricks" like this one. With a sound DB and application design, such "tricks" are actually remarkably easy to retro-fit in the few occasions and places when they area actually necessary.

Comment: splitting it yourself is telling the RDBMS, "no-no... I think I can handle data storage more efficiently than you can.  Let me do the heavy-lifting."  @PieterGeerkens is absolutely right.

Comment: thank you for your answers. It helps a lot to see your responses.

Comment: This is my particular concern, because I plan creating a small search engine which indexes about 3.000.000 sites and each sites will have approximately 30 words that are being indexed. This is my structure right now `site
--id
--url

word
--id
--word

appearances
--site_id
--word_id
--score` Should I keep this structure? Or should I create tables for A words, B words, C words etc? Same with the appearances table

Answer (score 0):

Select queries are faster on smaller tables.  You want to fit the indexes you have to sort on into your systems memory for better performance.
More importantly, tables should not be defined in order to hold a certain type of data, but instead a collection of associated data.  So if the data you are storing has logical differences they maybe should be broken into separate tables.

(Incomplete)

Pros:

- Faster data access
- Easier to copy or back up

Cons:

- Cannot easily compare data from different tables.

  - Union and join queries are needed to compare across tables

If you aren't concerned with some latency on your database it should be able to handle this on the other of a few million records without too much trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer? Do you think it is useful for my particular concern? Just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Here's some questions to ask yourself:

- Are the records all inter-related? Is there any way of cleanly dividing them into different, non-overlapping groups? Are these groups well defined, or subject to change?
- Is maintaining optimal write speed more of a concern than simplicity of access to data?
- Is there any way of partitioning the records into different categories?
- Is replication a concern? Redundancy?
- Are you concerned about transaction safety?
- Is it possible to re-structure the data later if you get the initial schema wrong?

There are a lot of ways of tackling this problem, but until you know the parameters you're working with, it's very hard to say.

Usually step one is to collect either a large corpus of genuine data, or at least simulate enough data that's reasonably similar to the genuine data to be structurally the same. Then you use your test data to try out different methods of storing and retrieving it.

Without any test data you're just stabbing in the dark